# Notification when changes was made by separate service

Tags: c#, wpf, quartz-scheduler

I have wpf application and Quartz.Net scheduler which run some job every 2 minutes.

This job get in response collection of objects. If in my json-file this objects not exists - job write them into file.

In WPF application I just want to display collection from file.

So I want to know when Job modified file.

---

Currently I don't have any other idea only to check file every 2 minutes and grab all items from it to display.

Comment: If file is the only source of that information - use [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the WPF application and the file are in the same operating system, you can use [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Otherwise, you may want to send a message from the Job process to the WPF application via a remote connection so that the WPF application would know to read the file again.

You could do it with [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx) where the Job would act as a server that the WPF application connects to and waits to be notified or via [raw sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is just for my case. Thanks